# Index Out of Range Exception (No Row at Position 0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, exception

I'm tring to call a stored procedure into a ActionResult from the view model.

When I tried to run my code I get an error

> *IndexOutOfRangeException was handled by user code - No Row at Position 0*

This is a newly created table and is empty but why isn't the stored procedure getting fired to insert the data?  Here is my code.

**Called Procedure CreateSecureRequestOutcome**

```
 public static void CreateSecureRequestOutcome(
 OracleTransaction trans,
 dsAdmin.SECURE_REQUEST_OUTCOMESRow outcomeRow)
  {
   using (OracleCommand cm = new OracleCommand())
  {
   cm.Connection = trans.Connection;
   cm.Transaction = trans;
   cm.CommandText = "TheService.PKG#SECURE_REQUEST.SECURE_REQUEST_OUTCOME";
   cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cm.AddToStatementCache = true;

 OracleParameter param = cm.Paramaters.Add("P_KEEP_PERSON_ID", OracleDBType.Decimal, Paremeter.Direction.Input);
 param.Value = keepPersonID;

 param = cm.Paramaters.Add("P_SECURE_REQUEST_GUID", OracleDBType.Raw, 16, null, Paremeter.Direction.Input);
 param.Value = outcomeRow.SECURE_REQUEST_GUID;

 param = cm.Parameters.Add("P_OUTCOME_TIMESTAMP", OracleDBType.Object, Paremeter.Direction.Output);
  }
}
 cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**IdentityConfirmed ViewModel Controller**

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult IdentityConfirmed(FormCollection collection)
{
 dsAdmin.SECURE_REQUESTS_OUTCOMESRow secReqOutRow;

using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection (OracleConnectionManager.GetProxyServiceConnetionString()))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (OracleTransaction trans = cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
          using (Data.dsAdminTableAdapters.SECURE_REQUESTS_OUTCOMESTableAdapter taOut = new Data.dsAdminTableAdapters.SECURE_REQUESTS_OUTCOMESTableAdapter();
          {
             typedDatasetFiller.ApplyConnection(taOut, cn);
             secReqOutRow = taOut.GetDataBySecureGUID(request.ToByteArray())[0];
          }
            secReqOutRow.OUTCOME_TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            Support.CreateSecureRequestOutcome(trans, secReqOutRow);
            trans.Commit();
      }
    cn.Close();
  }
 retrun View("IdentityConfirmed", vm);
}
```

Comment: Do you ever search your exception message in Google? On which line you get this error?

Comment: I get the error here secReqOutRow = taOut.GetDataBySecureGUID(request.ToByteArray())[0];

Comment: You should first check if `secReqOutRow` contains data before putting an indexer to it.

Comment: You using statement lacks the closing brace and there is a wrong semicolon. Could be just a typo?

Comment: @Abbas, the other way is right - before assigning anything to `secReqOutRow` he should verify that `GetDataBySecureGUID` contains data before putting an indexer to it.

Comment: That' what I meant, only explained it wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what do you *think* the error means? Why don't you debug properly?

To make it short, `GetDataBySecureGUID` returns an empty array, so accessing index 0 is not valid.

---

Please change your code as follows:

```
var results = taOut.GetDataBySecureGUID(request.ToByteArray());           
secReqOutRow = results[0];
```

Now set a breakpoint to the second line and inspect the value of `results`. How many elements are there?

I bet there's none, because that's exactly what the exception means. You're trying to access an element in a collection using an index that is larger than the maximum allowed index. The fact that you're trying to access the first element and get this error means that there is no first element, so there is no element at all in the collection.

Comment: Actually I put a break on that line and it is returning a value of byte numbers. xx00xxxxx-x0xx-xxxx-0120-xxxx-xxxxx2xx0xxx, numbers/letters.  So there is value

Comment: `request.ToByteArray()` may contain a value, but `GetDataBySecureGUID` returns an empty array/list. I suggest you debug what I'm going to write into my answer in a second and then tell me that there's data.

Comment: Your right it is 0, I'm so new to C#, how do I get the data?

Comment: That's stuff for a new question. So far, the error has been explained and you should mark the answer as accepted.